# Server side Pagination-control is not working when we get refreshed data in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

https://ciphertrick.com/2016/10/19/simple-pagination-for-angular2-applications/

Please see above link for server side pagination-control.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    template: `<h1>{{welcome}}</h1>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Game</th>
                        <th>Platform</th> 
                        <th>Release</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr *ngFor="let game of games | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage:page, id: '1'}; let i = index">
                        <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
                        <td>{{game.game}}</td>
                        <td>{{game.platform}}</td>
                        <td>{{game.release}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <pagination-controls (pageChange)="page = $event" id="1"
                      maxSize="5"
                      directionLinks="true"
                      autoHide="true">
                </pagination-controls>`
})
export class HomeComponent {
...
..
...
}
```

If I have new refreshed data in that case pager links are not working even if I am giving current page as 1. Still it's showing previous link enable.

Is there missing from my side? How to refresh pager like next and previous link after getting refreshed data in angular2 ?

Comment: The resource you cite is about 1 and a half years old. Have you considered looking for something a little newer? Like this: https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview

Comment: Ok let me try. Thank you.